# Maps V2: how to reach such an effect?

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi Thanks for your help.

I have been looking around but I cannot figure out how to get such a result with Maps V2.

**(Specifically the yellow square with the distance in on the borders)**

I think it was relatively easy with Maps V1, using an overlay.

But I do not have any idea on how to do it with.

Thanks for any suggestion!!

[image]

Comment: I dont know whether this could help!! take a look at this link               http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/02/draw-tranparent-circle-for-google-maps.html

Comment: @George thanks Georege but that is not what I need :-(